# System audio problems while Android emulator is running

Tags: sound, 18.04, android, emulation, android-emulator

I didn't use to have this problem but lately, while I have Google's Android emulator running, my system audio (not talking about the emulator's audio) sounds very distorted and metallic. Sometimes it will work fine for a minute and then start to sound messed up again. As soon as I shut down the emulator, everything sounds fine. I'm having this problem whether I use speakers or headphones.
I'm on Ubuntu 18.04 with the latest version of Android Studio.

Does anybody have any clue as to a fix or workaround?

Edit: As a workaround I'm starting the emulator from the terminal with

```
emulator -noaudio -avd my_avd
```

This seems to fix the sound issues but is obviously not an ideal solution.

Comment: I'm having a similar problem, but I am not sure what exactly is causing it. I started having this issue a few months ago on 16.04 HWE as well. I think it may be a bug in pulseaudio or alsa dealing with the pulseaudio integration. If nothing is playing when I start a VM (or some certain other apps), everything stays fine usually. If I have audio playing and start or stop the VM at the same time, audio becomes distorted, but is corrected usually when opening `pavucontrol` or system settings audio panel, or sometimes I will need to switching between digital/analog output.

Answer (score 36):

I did what was written on [this link](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1789459&p=10974454#post10974454) and it solved the problem for me.

In **/etc/pulse/default.pa** change `load-module module-udev-detect`
to `load-module module-udev-detect tsched=0`

and in **/etc/pulse/daemon.conf** change `; default-sample-rate = 44100` to `default-sample-rate = 48000`

Finally, restart pulseaudio with `pulseaudio -k` (or you simply restart the computer)

Comment: Thank you! Solved it for me on 18.04. Had to also reboot after `pulseaudio -k` before my music player started working again.

Comment: Thanks, solved the problem for me on 18.10.

Comment: Thanks fixed it for me on Ubuntu 19.04

Comment: Fixed it for me, running Manjaro KDE with 5.4 kernel

Comment: Thanks, fixed the issue for me on Arch Linux running Gnome

Comment: Fixed for me on pop os 20.04 as well.

Comment: Thank you very much this solved my problem on ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS

Comment: Amazing! It worked also on my Kubuntu with Ubuntu 20.04 3 LTS. I had to restart the computer as well. Thanks!

Comment: i solved my problem on ARCH Linux by this

Comment: Thank you so much Eduardo ... This fixed the problem :) I hope you have a great year ahead.

Comment: Well, Eduardo, saved my sounds. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, fixed it also on Ubuntu 22.04

Comment: Thanks! Works like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

it partially worked for me. I use a 25 inch monitor next to the notebook with my speakers connected to the monitor and with ubuntu 22.04.

When running both commands, I was no longer able to manually configure the speakers in the OS configuration menu and the sound only worked on the notebook (I didn't want that).

I deleted the second command (default-sample-rate = 48000) and kept the first one (load-module module-udev-detect tsched=0). After resetting pulseaudio it worked fine.

Detail: By default in the pulseaudio configuration of my PC, there was no 'default-sample-rate', not even in the old amount quoted in the post (default-sample-rate = 44100)